# Formulas breaking after copying workbook

Tags: google-sheets

First time poster, long time lurker. Until now, I've been able to find solutions to the issues that have popped up.

I have a "master" sheet that my org uses for business planning each week. I create a duplicate of the template each week. I have a tab within the workbook that rolls up information based on tab names, but it keeps breaking and the only solution I've been able to find (which is time consuming) is clicking into a cell, hitting enter (which "fixes" the formula), and then copying to the other cells with similar formulas.

The set up is generally this:

- Template has one "dashboard" tab with information that is copied 6x for each physical location of our facilities. eg, Los Angeles, San Francisco, etc. These tabs are then renamed accordingly. Instead of "Dashboard - Template" they're renamed to "Dashboard - Los Angeles".
- Rollup tab has formulas that reference each location-based tab.

But since these location-based tabs aren't created until I copy the workbook, these formulas throw an "#N/A - Error Argument must be a range." error. For instance:

- Template rollup tab has a formula "=sumif('Dashboard - Los Angeles'!Range,value,'Dashboard - Los Angeles'!Range).
- Formula is broken because the tab didn't exist when the template was copied.
- In order to fix, I need to click into the cell containing the formula, then hit enter, then copy that to the other similar cells with a difference reference value.

Any thoughts on how I could "mass-fix" these cells?

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. So while I'm certain that your post makes complete sense to you (who *can* see your spreadsheet), from out here... it's murky at best. I suggest that you share a link to a copy of the spreadsheet so that we can see and know what you see and know going in. Based solely on what I think I do understand, however, if your company has six and only six locations, why doesn't the template already have those six additional location tabs created in the template *before* it is copied?

Comment: Continuing my comment above, *template* usually means that a file is empty of specific data and contains only structures. So if your template were a true template, it would have all six location tabs already created and working, just with no date-specific (or otherwise specific) data entered. You'd make a copy. All formulas would work because all tabs would already be in place. Then you'd fill in data to the (presumably renamed) copy. Again, it seems obvious from "out here" that this is what one would do; but we can't actually see what you're working with yet. Feel free to share.

Comment: Your comment about my write up being murky is totally fair - I was worried that may be the case. Unfortunately, I can't share the sheet due to IP concerns. But your comment about the 6 facilities is apt. I used to have 6 tabs, but it made it more cumbersome to update any of the formulae within - instead of 1x, I had to do it 6x. But I may consider revisiting that setup...

Comment: If you are using array formulas where applicable (which is most of the time) instead of individual drag-down formulas, having six sheets and making changes should be fairly simple. You can also automate the entire "create new template" with script, which could run in such an order than new sheets are made, blank, and then existing formulas are copied over into the new sheets. But again, I'm talking "blind" here, so I can only offer these generalities.